# is Numpy's masked array memory efficient?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

I was wondering: are numpy's [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) able to store a compact representation of the available values? In other words, if I have a numpy array with no set values, will it be stored in memory with negligible size?

Actually, this is not just a casual question, but I need such memory optimization for an application I am developing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No a masked array is not more compact.

```
In [344]: m = np.ma.masked_array([1,2,3,4],[1,0,0,1])

In [345]: m
Out[345]: 
masked_array(data = [-- 2 3 --],
             mask = [ True False False  True],
       fill_value = 999999)

In [346]: m.data
Out[346]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [347]: m.mask
Out[347]: array([ True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

It contains both the original (full) array, and a mask.  The mask may be a scalar, or it may be a boolean array with the same shape as the data.

`scipy.sparse` stores just the nonzero values of an array, though the space savings depends on the storage format and the sparsity.  So you might simulate your masking with sparsity.  Or you could take ideas from that representation.

What do you plan to do with these arrays?  Just access items, or do calculations?

Masked arrays are most useful for data that is mostly good, with a modest number of 'bad' values.  For example, real life data series with occasional glitches, or monthly data padded to 31 days.  Masking lets you keep the data in a rectangular arrangement, and still calculate things like the mean and sum without useing the masked vales.

Comment: I am using them in order to store some calculation, in a "memoization" fashion. That means, I will calculate the value of a cell in the raster only when strictly required, and never have redundant computation. This I already implemented, if it was also memory efficient, that would have been better.

Comment: You could, in theory, use an object dtype array, where each object has this 'memoization' ability.   The array then is populated with pointers.  But such arrays are little more than lists.

Comment: I need the topology of an 2d array/matrix to represent 2d values, also because I am applying some gaussian convolutions afterwards. But if a dtype array has fast indexing I might consider it